# Wikipedia summary function gives PageError. Not fetching data from wikipedia

Tags: python, mediawiki

The folowing code gives me **PageError**

`print(wikipedia.summary("Bill Gates", sentences=2))`

`PageError: Page id "bill gets" does not match any pages. Try another id!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you surround the query in single quotes, it should use the literal string:

```
from mediawiki import MediaWiki
wikipedia = MediaWiki()
print(wikipedia.summary("'Bill Gates'", sentences=2))
```

> William Henry Gates III  (born October 28, 1955) is an American business magnate, software developer, and philanthropist. He is best known as the co-founder of Microsoft Corporation.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `summary` function expects an id of a page, not just a random name.
I would assume that the page id is the same as the part behind `/wiki/` in the link if you go to the Wikipedia page. In Bill Gate's case, the url is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates`.
This probably means that the id of this page is `Bill_Gates`.

So this probably works:

```py
print(wikipedia.summary("Bill_Gates", sentences=2))
```

Comment: It looks like that you and the question author share unmentioned background information. What Pythom module/library is invloved? Why is the wiki Dutch?

Comment: Good point, of course it should have been the English version, it was just an example.